# Why do I have two tables - AspNetUsers and ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC and EF. I created a `CatchmebgUser`, which inherits `IdentityUser`. I added a custom field for a photo in `CatchmebgUser` and applied the migrations.

Now I have two tables: `AspNetUsers` and `CatchmebgUser`.

When using the User object I was getting data from the `AspNetUsers` table until I added this line to `CatchmebgContext`:

```
builder.Entity<CatchmebgUser>().ToTable("CatchmebgUser");
```

Is there a way to get rid of the `AspNetUsers` table or I should have two separate tables for the users?

Comment: I would suggest leaving the AspNetUsers table if i were you. From here you can get roles and authentication for controllers. More over, removing this would  more than likely result in having to remove other AspNet tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inherit a custom `User` type from `IdentityUser`, you must instead use a derived version of `IdentityDbContext`, which allows you to specify this concrete types for user, role and primary keys used throughout the identity framework:

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CatchmebgUser, IdentityRole, string>
{
   ...
}
```

This way you don't have to add `builder.Entity<CatchmebgUser>().ToTable("CatchmebgUser")` configuration for your type, as the context will automatically use `DbSet<CatchmebgUser>` for the `Users` property.

Comment: I have that already: public class catchmebgContext : IdentityDbContext<CatchmebgUser>{} but I still have two tables

Comment: Then just remove the `DbSet` property you have added manually, it is just ok without it - then it should just generate the one `AspNetUsers` table

Comment: I mean remove the `builder.Entity<CatchmebgUser>().ToTable("CatchmebgUser");`

Comment: If I remove that, I am getting data /the photo/ from the AspNetUsers table and when I save the photo to the User photo property it is getting saved to the CatchmebgUser table

Comment: Yes, if you remove that, you will use `context.Users` in code, which will be of type `DbSet<CatchmebgUser>` and in the database the `AspNetUsers` table will have the additional properties you have added to the custom type

Comment: I updated my comment above. Without the builder line when using the User object to update the photo it gets saved in the CatchmebgUser table, not the AspNetUsers. but when reading the user from context.Users it pulls the photo from the AspNetUsers table. I don't understand why

Comment: Please add a new migration after removing the `builder` line, that should remove the table. Or alternatively reset migrations completely (in case you are still prototyping and can't lose data).

Comment: For instructions see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#remove-a-migration

Comment: If this solved your question, please consider accepting it as an answer, so that it is closed. Happy coding :-) !